# visual studio 2017 c++ native unit test framework not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

The scenario goes as follows:

1. I create some solution, Windows x64 console app
2. I write some classes, main file etc., nothing special
3. I create test project in this solution
4. I change in solution properties: platform for all to x64(that does not seem to change anything, just saying)

That's it, I DO NOT ADD ANY REFERENCE TO TEST PROJECT. I leave everything as generated by VS in the test project files As I want to build test project it fails and I get the following stack:

```
[2018-03-27 13:32:48 Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[2018-03-27 13:32:48 Error] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformV2()
[2018-03-27 13:32:48 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
[2018-03-27 13:32:48 Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0055039) ==========
[2018-03-27 13:32:48 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<ExecuteRequest>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Wait(Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<StartDiscoverTests>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoverSelectedOperation.<ExecuteInternal>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteWithEvents>d__40.MoveNext()
[2018-03-27 13:33:22 Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[2018-03-27 13:33:22 Warning] Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework Framework45 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) will not be part of run: 
UnitTest1.dll is built for Framework None and Platform X64.
 Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.
[2018-03-27 13:33:22 Error] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformV2()
[2018-03-27 13:33:22 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
[2018-03-27 13:33:22 Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,003502) ==========
[2018-03-27 13:33:22 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<ExecuteRequest>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Wait(Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<StartDiscoverTests>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoverSelectedOperation.<ExecuteInternal>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteWithEvents>d__40.MoveNext()
[2018-03-27 13:36:04 Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[2018-03-27 13:36:04 Error] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformV2()
[2018-03-27 13:36:04 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
[2018-03-27 13:36:04 Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0030025) ==========
[2018-03-27 13:36:04 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<ExecuteRequest>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Wait(Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<StartDiscoverTests>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoverSelectedOperation.<ExecuteInternal>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteWithEvents>d__40.MoveNext()
[2018-03-27 13:36:12 Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[2018-03-27 13:36:12 Error] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformV2()
[2018-03-27 13:36:12 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
[2018-03-27 13:36:12 Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0035031) ==========
[2018-03-27 13:36:12 Error] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.UnitTestExtensionDiscoverer.GetAllEnabledExtensions(ILogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.UpdateTestPlatform(Lazy`1 testPlatform)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GetTestPlatformBySettings(ITestExecutorLauncher testExecutorLauncher, String testRunSettings, Boolean isAppContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestDiscoveryRequest.<CreateRequests>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<RunRequests>d__98.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.<ProcessRequest>d__97.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<ExecuteRequest>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Wait(Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RequestFactory.<Execute>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<StartDiscoverTests>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoverSelectedOperation.<ExecuteInternal>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteWithEvents>d__40.MoveNext()
```

I've been searching for a while now, anybody has any clue what is wrong there? I tested it on 2 different VS solutions, same results. Please help!

Comment: @AlBundy sorry I'm just a bit tired, I corrected 2 typos, well can we move on to the actual problem?

Comment: Log shows `test started` and `test finished`. Description shows `As I want to build test project it fails`. I doubt that you did what you described.

Comment: I wrote that because the error stack shows when I BUILD not RUN the tests. So BUILDING failed, right? It also says: `0 found` but there is one empty test so it isn't doing it's job is it? Additionaly in the Test Explorer the progressbar goes infinitely without any results.

Comment: @CharlieB - If you are on version 15.5.x (for x > something) it just doesn't work. Try upgrading to 15.6

Comment: @BoPersson My version is `15.6.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the solution. All I had to do is go to Testee Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> General and change Configuration type from `.exe.` to `.lib` - static library. Cheers!